# I need to return a new set that contains the elements of a and b in a union

Tags: java

I need to return a new set that contains the elements of a and b in a union

```
public static Set<Integer> union(Set<Integer> a, Set<Integer> b) {

    List<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>(a.size() + b.size());


    private void add(List<Integer> toAddTo,List<Integer> iterateOver) {
        for(Integer num:iterateOver){
            if(toAddTo.indexOf(num) == -1) {
                toAddTo.add(num);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my attempt, Im not sure what to do from here

Comment: Are you aware of the `addAll` method of the `Set` interface?

Comment: Why do you have list there? Sets don't have duplicates. Union of `[1,2]` and `[2,3]` is `[1,2,3]` not `[1,2,2,3]`. Create one set which will hold elements from a and add to it elements from b. then return that set.

Comment: Im not aware of either of those and I dont know im not sure what to do

Comment: You should NOT change the question once people start answering it - it just invalidates their answers.  If you have a new question, then ASK a new question.

Comment: It looks now like you simply copy-paste posted solution into your question with one typo (you have `=` instead of `+`). Don't do that. Place for solution is in answer section, place for problem description is in question. Also don't change topic of question. It invalidates posted answers. If you have new question ask it in separate post.

Comment: Your new title has nothing to do with your original question and with your attempt. I rolled it back. Again, if you have new question ask it in separate post (use "Ask Question" button on top-right corner of this site).

Comment: **Moderator Note:** As @Pshemo said, please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you have a new question, please create a new post, by clicking, [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-rout‌​e-for-a-dissociation-request)

Answer (score 2):

Do not work on lists, if you need sets.
Do not modify input parameters... (another tip).

```
public static Set<Integer> union(Set<Integer> a, Set<Integer> b) {
    Set<Integer> toReturn = new HashSet<>(a.size() + b.size());
    toReturn.addAll(a);
    toReturn.addAll(b);
    return toReturn;
}
```